# python: overload operator > with different types

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, operator-overloading, operators

tell me how to overload the operator > (**lt**) or < (**gt**) etc so that it can work with different types (especially with 0)

for example:

```
class CRational(object):

    def __init__(self, a = 0, b = 1):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        
    def __neg__(self):
        return CRational(-self.a, self.b)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return CRational(self.a * other.b + other.a * self.b, self.b * other.b)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return CRational(self.a * other.b - other.a * self.b, self.b * other.b)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return CRational(self.a * other.a, self.b * other.b)

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        return CRational(self.a * other.b, self.b * other.a)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.a * other.b == other.a * self.b

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.a * other.b < other.a * self.b

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.a * other.b <= other.a * self.b

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.a * other.b > other.a * self.b

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.a * other.b >= other.a * self.b
```

error output:

> File "lessons/python/square_eq.py", line 66, in __gt __
> return self.a * other.b > other.a * self.b AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'b'

in code:

```
s_a = "" if a > 0 else "-"
```

how do you fix it?

```
s_a = "" if a > CRational(0) else "-"
```

the method described above helps, but it is not beautiful :)

Comment: For your code examples, I can't see what `a` and I don't have any other context for what it is trying to accomplish. Can you please include them.

Comment: test the type of your `other` argument inside the function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to compare a `CRational` object with an int then your `__gt__` method should works with integers too. I.e., if `other` is an integer, you clearly can't do something like `other.b`. Here is a possible solution:

```
class CRational:
    def __init__(self, a = 0, b = 1):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def __gt__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, CRational):
            return self.a * other.b > other.a * self.b
        elif isinstance(other, int):
            # Compare self (a CRational object) with other (an int)
            # TODO
        else:
            raise NotImplemented()
```

Now you can do something like this:

```
a = CRational()
if a > 3:
    ...
```

Be careful though! Even if you implement correctly all the methods, you still can't do `3 > a`. Order is important!! `3 > a` would call the `__gt__` method of the int class. You can only do `a > 3`, `a < 3`, `a >= 3` etc.

Answer (score 2):

With regards to your error output: you are getting the error because your "other" is an int and `CRational.__gt__` is trying to access an attribute that it does not have a `b`:

```
def __gt__(self, other):  # passing in an int here
        return self.a * other.b > other.a * self.b
```

With regards to your code example, assuming `a` is another `CRational` object, then `a > 0` will cause the `AttributeError` you are seeing above and the only way to fix it is by comparing it with either another `CRational` object or some other object that has attribues `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're wanting to test for what kind of object you are working with.  Maybe something like:

```python
import numbers

def __gt__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, type(self)):
        return self.a * other.b > other.a * self.b
    elif isinstance(other, numbers.Number):
        return self.a > other
    else:
        err_str = "Unknown type in comparison with %s object: %s" % (type(self).__name__, type(other).__name__)
        raise(TypeError(err_str))
```

Here, type(self) is a generic way of getting the CRational class.  That way you don't have to modify the class's code if you simply change the name later.

isinstance checks to see if a given object is of the given type, or a child type.  [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance).

I made up the numeric case, because I don't know how you'd want to define that.